# Unique unit normal vector (supporting hyperplane) of strictly convex set

Tags: functional-analysis

When I try to prove this problem, in $\mathbb{R}^n$, we know that a set $K$ which is closed, convex, then every point $x_0\in \partial K$ admits a supporting hyperplane, i.e there exists a vector $\alpha\in \mathbb{R}^n$ such that
$$ \langle y, \alpha\rangle  \leq \langle x,\alpha\rangle $$
for every $y\in K$. Where $\langle.,.\rangle$ denote the Euclid scalar product on $\mathbb{R^n}$. This result can be proved by using Hahn--Banach theorem in $\mathbb{R}^n$, ...etc. But such a vector like $\alpha$ for $x_0$ is not unique, incase $K$ is a triangle in $\mathbb{R}^2$ there are too many vector like that at every vertex. 
But if $K$ is strictly convex, i.e if $a,b\in K$ then for every $t\in (0,1)$
$$tx + (1-t)y \in \text{the interior of}\; K$$
In this case, I think the normal vector like that is unique at each point $x_0\in \partial K$, but I cannot prove this. Is this true?

I observe that if the supporting hyperplane $H =\{x: \langle \alpha, x\rangle = \langle \alpha, x_0 \rangle\}$ much have
$$ H\cap K = \{x_0\}$$
incase $K$ is strictly convex.

Comment: No it's not true. But if $\partial K$ be smooth then it must be true.

Comment: @Abdollah why is it true when it is smooth? it seems geometrically obvious, but i am struggling with proving it.

Comment: Just note that "Normal vector of supporting hyper plane must be equal with gradient of $f$ if we can write $K = f^{-1}(c)$ for a smooth $f$ and real number $c$". Existence of real function $f$ and real number $c$ is another story . . . !